# Git/Dreamweaver - Working with Branches

Tags: git, github, branch, dreamweaver

I recently started working with branches in Git. I also use Adobe Dreamweaver CS6. I am trying to use the master branch as my "live" directory that is the actual live code on my website. I'd like to use other branches basically to just test with code, I'd merge them with the master branch to submit the final product. In Dreamweaver I have the local site folder set to the Git repository. In Dreamweaver I also have it set to automatically upload files on save. The only problem with that is that now whenever I save a file in Dreamweaver on either the master branch or another branch, the files are automatically uploaded to FTP whether I want them to or not. I think I will some how need to make the branches unique to Dreamweaver so it does not automatically upload master branch file changes. How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git` to have your website updated automatically, instead of using FTP to transfer the changed files. I will describe a simplified set up that allows updating the code on the web server when you push changes to the master branch using git, and even though this is a simplification, I hope that it may help as a reference (I have seen this pattern many times so I hope that it will be useful).

1. Create a bare (aka remote) repository (there are free and business online services like github or bitbucket or you can have your own server for this purpose [often in an enterprise environment]). This repository acts as an intermediary between developers’ local copies and the production server.

   (see [the reference](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server))
2. Point your local git repository to the remote

   `git remote add origin git://example.com/repo/project.git`

   (see [the reference](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes))
3. Push all branches and tags from the local repo to the remote

   `git push --all`
   `git push --tags`
4. Create a git hook to update the server copy when pushed to the master branch.
   Git hook is a script with pre-defined name that you can place in the `hooks` folder in the root of the repository.

   (see [the reference](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks))

   This step requires that `git` is installed on the web server as well if the bare repository is on a different machine (then it might also be necessary to have SSH access to the web server).

Now, when you update the code on your local machine and want to publish the changes to update the live website, you just push the committed changes to the master branch:

`git commit ...`
`git push`

Assuming that the git hook from the step 4 is configured to update the website only when pushing the master branch, you can use other branches for development and testing.

You may also be interested in the Continuous Integration process or build software like Jenkins CI or Hudson CI.

This is somewhat a more general approach that is not limited to a specific editor or IDE like Dreamweaver but I hope that this still helps.

Comment: Now that GIT is built into Dreamweaver 19, can a hook or something be set up so that changes to the master branch automatically get pushed to the web server, and all changes on other branches automatically go to a testing server?